# Merging video with original orientation

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, cgaffinetransform, avmutablecomposition

***I have a link I can DM for a minimum working example!***

---

**Recording Videos**

For recording, the `AVCaptureConnection` for an `AVCaptureSession`, I set `isVideoMirrored` to true when using the front camera and false when using the back camera. All in portrait orientation.

**Saving Videos**

When I save videos, I perform an `AVAssetExportSession`. If I used the front camera, I want to maintain the `isVideoMirrored = true`, so I create an `AVMutableComposition` to set the `AVAsset` video track's `preferredTransform` to `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0).rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))`. For the back camera, I export the `AVAsset` as outputted.

Part of my saving code:

```
        if didCaptureWithFrontCamera {
        
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        
        let assetVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).last!
        let assetAudioTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).last!
        
        let compositionVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        
        try? compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: asset.duration), of: assetVideoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        try? compositionAudioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: asset.duration), of: assetAudioTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        
        compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0).rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))
        
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720) else {
            handler(nil)
            return
        }
        
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { handler(exportSession) }
        
    } else {
        
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720) else {
            handler(nil)
            return
        }
        
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { handler(exportSession)  }
    }
```

**Merging Videos**

Later, to view the saved videos, I want to merge them together as a single video and maintain each by their original orientation via `AVMutableComposition`.

What partially has worked is setting the video track of `AVMutableComposition` to the `preferredTransform` property of the video track of an individual `AVAsset` video. The only problem is that a single orientation is applied to all the videos (i.e. mirroring isn't applied in a back camera recorded video and the same is applied to the front camera video too).

From solutions I've come across it appears I need to apply `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`, but in trying to do so, the `AVAssetExportSession` doesn't seem to factor in the `videoComposition` instructions at all.

Any guidance would be ***extremely*** appreciated as I haven't been able to solve it for the life of me...

My attempted merge code:

```
func merge(videos: [AVURLAsset], for date: Date, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL, _ asset: AVAssetExportSession)->()) {
let videoComposition = AVMutableComposition()
var lastTime: CMTime = .zero

var count = 0
var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)

guard let videoCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else { return }
guard let audioCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else { return }

for video in videos {
    
    if let videoTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[safe: 0] {
            
        //this is the only thing that seems to work, but work not in the way i'd hope where each video keeps its original orientation
       //videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
        
        if let audioTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[safe: 0] {
            
            do {
                
                try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: videoTrack, at: lastTime)
                try audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: audioTrack, at: lastTime)
                
                let layerInstruction = videoCompositionInstruction(videoTrack, asset: video, count: count)

                let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
                videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime, duration: video.duration)
                videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

                instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)

            } catch {
                return
            }
            lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, video.duration)
            count += 1
            
        } else {
            
            do {
                
                try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: videoTrack, at: lastTime)
                
                let layerInstruction = videoCompositionInstruction(videoTrack, asset: video, count: count)

                let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
                videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime, duration: video.duration)
                videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

                instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)

            } catch {
                return
            }
            
            lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, video.duration)
            count += 1
        }
    }
}

let mutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
mutableVideoComposition.instructions = instructions
mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = renderSize

dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
let date = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

let mergedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merged-\(date)" + ".mp4")

guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
exporter.outputURL = mergedURL
exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
exporter.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
completion(mergedURL, exporter)
}

func videoCompositionInstruction(_ firstTrack: AVAssetTrack, asset: AVAsset, count: Int) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)

let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: firstTrack)

let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
let t = assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform // new transform fix
let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(t)

if assetInfo.isPortrait {

    let scaleToFitRatio = renderSize.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
    let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
    var finalTransform = assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
    
    if assetInfo.orientation == .rightMirrored || assetInfo.orientation == .leftMirrored {
        finalTransform = finalTransform.translatedBy(x: -t.ty, y: 0)
    }
    instruction.setTransform(t, at: CMTime.zero)

} else {

    let renderRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: renderSize.width, height: renderSize.height)
    let videoRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: assetTrack.naturalSize).applying(assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform)

    let scale = renderRect.width / videoRect.width
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: renderRect.width / videoRect.width, y: (videoRect.height * scale) / assetTrack.naturalSize.height)
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: .zero, y: ((renderSize.height - (videoRect.height * scale))) / 2)

    instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform.concatenating(transform).concatenating(translate), at: .zero)
}

if count == 0 {
    instruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: asset.duration)
}

return instruction
}

func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
var isPortrait = false

if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
    assetOrientation = .right
    isPortrait = true
} else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
    assetOrientation = .rightMirrored
    isPortrait = true
} else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
    assetOrientation = .left
    isPortrait = true
} else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
    assetOrientation = .leftMirrored
    isPortrait = true
} else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
    assetOrientation = .up
} else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
    assetOrientation = .down
}
return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
}

extension AVAssetTrack {

var fixedPreferredTransform: CGAffineTransform {
    var t = preferredTransform
    switch(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d) {
    case (1, 0, 0, 1):
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = 0
    case (1, 0, 0, -1):
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = naturalSize.height
    case (-1, 0, 0, 1):
        t.tx = naturalSize.width
        t.ty = 0
    case (-1, 0, 0, -1):
        t.tx = naturalSize.width
        t.ty = naturalSize.height
    case (0, -1, 1, 0):
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = naturalSize.width
    case (0, 1, -1, 0):
        t.tx = naturalSize.height
        t.ty = 0
    case (0, 1, 1, 0):
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = 0
    case (0, -1, -1, 0):
        t.tx = naturalSize.height
        t.ty = naturalSize.width
    default:
        break
    }
    return t
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your transformations are correct, I updated your `merge` function.

The main change is using a single `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` with multiple `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`, and passing the correct `CMTime` value to for the layer instruction to be executed at.

```
  func merge(videos: [AVURLAsset],
             for date: Date,
             completion: @escaping (_ url: URL, _ asset: AVAssetExportSession)->()) {
    let videoComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    guard let videoCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video,
                                                                       preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)),
          let audioCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio,
                                                                       preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    else { return }
    
    
    var lastTime: CMTime = .zero
    var layerInstructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()
    
    for video in videos {
      guard let videoTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[safe: 0] else { return }
      
      // add audio track if available
      if let audioTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[safe: 0] {
        do {
          try audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration),
                                                    of: audioTrack,
                                                    at: lastTime)
        } catch {
          return
        }
      }
      
      // add video track
      do {
        try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration),
                                                  of: videoTrack,
                                                  at: lastTime)
        let layerInstruction = makeVideoCompositionInstruction(videoTrack,
                                                               asset: video,
                                                               atTime: lastTime)
        layerInstructions.append(layerInstruction)
      } catch {
        return
      }
      
      lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, video.duration)
    } // end for..in videos
    
    let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)
    
    let videoInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    videoInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: lastTime)
    videoInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructions
    
    let mutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.instructions = [videoInstruction]
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = renderSize
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    
    let mergedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merged-\(date)" + ".mp4")
    
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoComposition,
                                              presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
    exporter.outputURL = mergedURL
    exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
    exporter.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    completion(mergedURL, exporter)
  }
  
  func makeVideoCompositionInstruction(_ videoTrack: AVAssetTrack,
                                       asset: AVAsset,
                                       atTime: CMTime) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
    let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)
    
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    
    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    let t = assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform // new transform fix
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(t)
    
    if assetInfo.isPortrait {
      let scaleToFitRatio = renderSize.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
      let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
      var finalTransform = assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
      
      if assetInfo.orientation == .rightMirrored || assetInfo.orientation == .leftMirrored {
        finalTransform = finalTransform.translatedBy(x: -t.ty, y: 0)
      }
      instruction.setTransform(t, at: atTime)
      
    } else {
      
      let renderRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: renderSize.width, height: renderSize.height)
      let videoRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: assetTrack.naturalSize).applying(assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform)
      
      let scale = renderRect.width / videoRect.width
      let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: renderRect.width / videoRect.width,
                                        y: (videoRect.height * scale) / assetTrack.naturalSize.height)
      let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: .zero,
                                        y: ((renderSize.height - (videoRect.height * scale))) / 2)
      
      instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform.concatenating(transform).concatenating(translate),
                               at: atTime)
    }
    
    // if atTime = 0, we can assume this is the first track being added
    if atTime == .zero {
      instruction.setOpacity(0.0,
                             at: asset.duration)
    }
    
    return instruction
  }
```

Comment: i tried the code but the orientation is still off...the video picture moreover also displays -90 degrees from portrait view :(. any additional thoughts?

Comment: @Chris can you post a minimal working project on github?

Comment: sorry for the delay! is there a way i can forward you the link directly?